# iMacros failing to find input with data-bind-event-click

Tags: imacros

I'm currently testing iMacros with the Shopify backend to make copying data from external sources easier.

This is the HTML:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" data-bind="product.title" data-bind-event-click="Shopify.AddProductFunnel.clickProductTitle()" id="product-name" placeholder="Short Sleeve T-Shirt" class="next-input" size="30" type="text" name="product[title]" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;">
```

Here is the macro:

```
'Now fill them in a form. This is only one example. You could use it also as part of link  
URL GOTO=https://****.myshopify.com/admin/products/new   
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:product-name ATTR=NAME:product[title] CONTENT=***Extract<SP>and<SP>Fill<SP>Demo*** 
'
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
RuntimeError: element INPUT specified by NAME:product[title] was not found, line: 18
```

Comment: The Imacros seems to populate the input box fine, I am using the provided HTML and IMACROS code on Chrome 63.0.3239.84, can you provide the website link where the error occours?

Comment: @NarenMurali Unfortunately it's in the backend of my webstore and the other site I'm taking it from is a closed off vendor site